# How to share a GL context between CGL and Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl

Source code A uses a `CGLContextObj`.

Source code B uses a `QGLContext`.

Is there any way that these pieces of code could share a GL context?

- Can a `QGLContext` be set up from a `CGLContextObj`?
- Can a `CGLContextObj` be set up from a `QGLContext`?
- Can both a `QGLContext` and a `CGLContextObj` be set up from some other type?

(I understand that `CGLContextObj` is specific to Apple to while `QGLContext` is platform-independent. Let's assume the code is only going to run on a Mac.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current GL context is [stored in a common thread-local variable](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Context), regardless of which application framework you're using on a given platform.  So after you set up a `QGLContext`, you could call `CGLGetCurrentContext()` to get the corresponding `CGLContextObj`.